# Filter data within function over do.call

Tags: r, do.call

Data:

```
 data <- structure(list(index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
hour = c(13, 13, 13, 1, 1, 1), minutes = c(31, 
     31, 32, 36, 36, 36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1067L, 
    1069L, 1070L, 1072L, 1073L, 1074L))
```

use `do.call`:

```
func <- function(hourFilt, minutesFilt){
  filt <- data[data$hour == hourFilt & data$minutes == minutesFilt, ]$idx
  sum(filt)
}

do.call(func, list(hourFilt = 1:5, minutesFilt = 31:35))
```

I am aware what the warning means:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In data$hour == hourFilt :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

but I would expect, that the function is called five times and not only once, resulting in that warning and wrong result.

**Expected result:**

```
mapply(func, hourFilt = 1:5, minutesFilt = 31:35)
1 2 0 0 0
```

However, I would prefer using `do.call()` as it is faster.

**Edit: Adding intention**
I want to filter a dataset of 25k-200k rows for a specific time. The filtering on the original data set will result in three rows. And for that result i want to sum up a given variable - here: index. That process will be repeated for a few hundred times. Therefore, i looked into `mapply()`, `do.call()`. Performance does matter, thats why i prefer `do.call()`.

Comment: If one had not seen your code, how would you describe your intention? Please edit to reflect the expected output more explicitly.

Comment: sure, see my edit.

Comment: If I run your function and then use `mapply`  like `mapply(func, hourFilt = 1:5, minutesFilt = 31:35)` I get all 0's on your `data` which makes sense since for the first case `data$index[data$hour == 1 & data$minutes == 31]` returns `numeric(0)`. How are you getting 1 ?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's fair to say that `do.call` is "faster" as they do completely different things. `do.call()` will only ever call a function once with one set of parameters. You seem to want to call a function multiple times with different parameters. Those are very different operations. I'm not sure `do.call` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `do.call` is not to run a function multiple times, such as mapply would do, but to run a function once over a list of elements. This is very practical when working with large lists and trying to apply *a single function* to *all arguments* of the list. A typical example would be `do.call(cbind,list)`, if you want to create a table in which each column is an element of the list.

So, when you run `do.call(func, list(hourFilt = 1:5, minutesFilt = 31:35))` R is running

```
func(hourFilt = 1:5, minutesFilt = 31:35)
```

And thus you get your errors. All elements of the list are being passed at once to the arguments of your `func()`.

I think `mapply()` might be the best solution to your problem. If you are concerned about performance, you could try `mcmapply()` from the `parallel` package, which can parallelize the computation (not on Windows).

```
corenum <- parallel::detectCores()-1
parallel::mcmapply(func,hourFilt=1:5,minutesFilt=31:35,mc.cores=corenum)
```

Or if you are working on Windows, the more cumbersome `parSapply()` might work for you:

```
corenum <- parallel::detectCores()-1
cl<-parallel::makeCluster(corenum)

#export the objects so that the parallel sockets can use them
parallel::clusterExport(cl,c("func","hourFilt","minutesFilt","data"))

result<-parallel::parSapply(cl,1:length(hourFilt),function(i){
  func(hourFilt[i],minutesFilt[i])
})
```

**PS:** With your dataset the expected result should be `0 0 0 0 0`